# Is it possible to get a and b to one side of this equation with the other variables on the other side?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the equation $cab = \dfrac ef - 2dfb$, is it possible to get $a$ and $b$ to one side of the equation with $c$, $d$, $e$, and f on the other side? Basically I want to solve that equation for $ab$. I can’t seem to do it but I don’t want to assume it’s impossible.

Answer (score 0):

In other words,  you’re asking if there a function $F$ such that $F(ab,c,d,e,f) = cab - \frac ef - 2dfb$ (so this equation becomes $F(ab,c,d,e,f) = 0$). Let’s do some things.

Firstly, $\frac d{da}F(ab,c,d,e,f) = cb$. On the other hand, $\frac d{da}F(ab,c,d,e,f) = bF'_1(ab,c,d,e,f)$, so $F'_1(ab,c,d,e,f) = c$.

Secondly, $\frac d{db}F(ab,c,d,e,f) = ca - 2df$. It should also equal $\frac d{db}F(ab,c,d,e,f) = aF'_1(ab,c,d,e,f)$, so $F'_1(ab,c,d,e,f) = c - \frac{2df}a$.

Oops, it can’t be! So, there are no such $F$ — at least, $F$ having a partial derivative $F'_1$. Which, I presume, is necessary in your context(?).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Let's simplify a little, and assume that all $c, d,f$ are non zero. Then we can write $$ab=\frac{e}{cf}-\frac{2df}{c}b$$
This equation shows that your quantity of interest ($ab$) can take any value, depending on the value of $b$.